# Display a loading modal after confirming the onbeforeunload pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display a loading modal when the user goes to another page of my site.

Since more than half of the pages are forms, I decided to display the pop-up by default if the user does not save his data. Here is the javascript code :

```
$("input, textarea, select").bind('change', function() {
    $("button[type='submit']").click(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            return
        }
    })

    window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
        var message = '?'
        var e = evt || window.event
        e.returnValue = message
        return message
    }
})

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form.modal-trigger').submit(function() {
        $('#submit-modal').show()
    })

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        $('#submit-modal').show()
    }
})
```

When the user clicks `Cancel`, all is well, but when he selects `OK` my modal is not displayed.

Is there any way to display it after the user selects `OK` ?